# Grid of Rectangles

Tags: c++, beginner

I am posting my first project in C++ (and also my first in object-oriented programming), can someone review it and cross check that everything I have coded is alright? If you have any tips to improve my code please tell me. The project is running and working. This is a home assignment and I know there are no default constructor (that is the way the teacher wants it).

The project consists of 3 classes: `Point`, `Rectangle` and `Grid`. `Grid` builds a dynamic array of `Rectangle`s.

I am not sure when I used  destructor, I must have implemented  it inside the class?

Are `friend` classes necessary in this context or is there another way to implement it?

```
class Point
{


public:
Point(int x, int y);
int getX() const;
int getY() const;
void setX(int x);
void setY(int y);
void print() const;

friend class Rectangle;  



private:
int x, y;
};


Point::Point(int x,int y )
{
 setX(x);
 setY(y);
}

void Point::setX(int x)
{
    if(x<0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid value for x, Setting to default\n";
        this->x=0;
    }
    else
        this->x=x;
}

void Point::setY(int y)
{
    if(y<0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid value for y, Setting to default\n";
        this->y=0;
    }
    else
        this->y=y;
}

int Point::getX() const 
{
    return x;
} 

int Point::getY() const 
{
    return y;
}

void Point::print() const
{
        cout <<"X:"<< this->x <<"  "<<"Y:" << this->y ;
        cout <<"  ";
}




class Rectangle
{
public:

Rectangle(int l, int u, int w, int h, int color);
int getColor() const;
void setColor(int color);
bool contains(const Point &p) const;
void print() const;

friend class Grid ; // is there any other way it can work without friend ?

private:
const Point topLeft, bottomRight;
int color;
};



#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int l=0,int u=0,int w=0,int h=0,int color=0):topLeft(l,u),bottomRight(w+(topLeft.getX()),u+h),color(color)
{   

}

int Rectangle::getColor() const
{
    return color;
}

void Rectangle::setColor(int color)
{
    this->color=color;
}



bool Rectangle::contains(const Point &p) const
{
    int x,y,h,w;
    x=p.getX();
    y=p.getY();

    if(p.x>=topLeft.x && p.x<=bottomRight.x && p.y>=topLeft.y && p.y<=bottomRight.y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}


void Rectangle::print() const
{
    cout << endl;
    cout<<"Rectangle top-left=("<<topLeft.x<<","<<topLeft.y<<")"<<"bottom-right=("<<bottomRight.x<<","<<bottomRight.y<<")"<<"color="<<color;
    cout << endl;
}






class Grid
{

public:
Grid(int tileW, int tileH, int width, int height, int color);
Rectangle& getRectAt(const Point &p);
void print() const;

~Grid()
{
  //cout <<"Destroy " ;
  delete []recs;  // not sure if it is the right place

}


private:
int count;
Rectangle **recs;
};




Grid::Grid(int tileW, int tileH, int width, int height, int color)  // האם ניתן להניח את תקינות הקלט ? 
{
  int i ,j; 
  count=height*width;
  recs=new Rectangle* [count];

  for(i=0;i<height;i++)
   for(j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        recs[j+(i*width)]=new Rectangle (j*tileW,tileH*i,tileW,tileH,color);
    }
}

Rectangle& Grid::getRectAt(const Point &p)
{
    Rectangle *r; 
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)     
        if(recs[i]->contains(p) )
        {
          cout<<"match";
          cout << endl;
          return *(recs)[i];
        }
    cout<<"No mach";
    cout << endl;
    return *(recs)[0];
}

void Grid::print() const 
{

 for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
      recs[i]->print();

  } 

}


void main() 
{   
  Grid g(4, 2, 3, 2, 0);
  cout << "-- before setColor(2) --" << endl; 
  g.print();
  Point p(5, 1);
  g.getRectAt(p).setColor(2);
  cout << "-- after setColor(2) --" << endl; 
  g.print(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace std;
```

This is a bad habit and not one you really want to develop. It leads to various naming conflicts that can be a pain to deal with. Typing `std::` every so often isn't that big of a pain.

---

"dynamic array of Rectangles" should translate into `vector<Rectangles>`. If you don't and use a pointer then you need to take responsibility of cleanup and following the rule of 0/3/5 as needed.

As is you had a leak in your destuctor because you didn't delete the individual `Rectangle`s in the array of pointers.

```
class Grid
{

    public:
    Grid(int tileW, int tileH, int width, int height, int color);
    Rectangle& getRectAt(const Point &p);
    void print() const;

    // no destructor needed because std::vector gets properly auto-destructed (rule of 0)

    private:
    std::vector<Rectangle> recs;

};
```

Note that the `vector` will be keeping the `Rectangle` by value in its internal array.

---

Friend classes are only needed when the other party needs access to internals that it cannot get otherwise. Making Rectangle a `friend` of `Point` is not needed because `Point` has getters for its fields and `Grid` access use any private data from `Rectangle`.

Comment: I got your point about namespace std and fiend classsses  ,I didn't understand how to use vector ? . About the destructor   as  it's part of the assignment and I must implement it . Can you show how to write  it ? Can i write the destructor in the cpp file ?

Comment: Can you show how to write the destructor ?