# C++ operator overloading for matrix operations

Tags: c++, beginner, matrix, overloading

Please check the code to see if there anything I can improve .
Everyting is working as expected.

matrix.h

```
#ifndef Matrix_h
#define Matrix_h
using namespace std;
class Matrix
{
 private:
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int **Mat;


  public:
    Matrix (const int &rows,const int &cols);
    Matrix(const Matrix &other);
    ~Matrix ();
    int* & operator[](const int &index) const ;
    void operator=(const Matrix &otherM )const;
    Matrix  operator -()const;
    Matrix  Matrix::operator -(const Matrix &t)const;
    Matrix  Matrix::operator +(const Matrix &t)const ;
    Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const Matrix &t)const;
    Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const int &num)const;

    friend  Matrix Matrix::operator *(const int & num,const Matrix &m)
    {
     return (m*num);
    }


    friend Matrix  Matrix::operator +(const int &num,const Matrix &t)
    {
     return (num+t);
    }


    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & os , const Matrix & m )
    {
        for(int i=0;i<m.rows;i++)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<m.cols;j++)
            cout <<m.Mat[i][j]<<"  " ;
           cout <<endl ;
        }
    return os ;
    }
};
#endif
```

matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<assert.h>
#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(const int &rows,const int &cols )//constructor of class Matrix
{
    this->rows=rows; 
    this->cols=cols;
    Mat=new int* [cols];
    assert(Mat);
    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++)
    {
       Mat[i]=new int[cols];
       assert(Mat[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        Mat[i][j]=0;            
}

 Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &other)  //copy constructor
{
    this->cols=other.cols;
    this->rows=other.rows;
    this->Mat=new int* [other.rows];
    assert(this->Mat);
    for(int i =0;i<other.rows;i++)
    {
       this->Mat[i]=new int[other.cols];
       assert(this->Mat[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<other.rows;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<other.cols;j++)
            this->Mat[i][j]=other[i][j];
}


int* & Matrix::operator [](const int &index) const 
{
  return  Mat [index];
}

void Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &otherM )const
{
    if(this->Mat !=otherM.Mat && this->cols==otherM.cols && this->rows==otherM.rows)
     {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            this->Mat[i][j]=otherM.Mat[i][j];
     }
}


 Matrix  Matrix::operator-()const  
{
    Matrix temp(this->rows,this->cols); 
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=this->Mat[i][j]*-1;
   return temp;
}


 Matrix  Matrix::operator +(const Matrix &t)const  //add 2 matrix
{
    Matrix temp(this->rows,this->cols);  
    if (this->rows!=t.rows ||this->cols!=t.cols)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<this->rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<this->cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=this->Mat[i][j];
       return temp;
    }
    else
     {      
         for(int i=0;i<this->rows;i++)
             for(int j=0;j<this->cols;j++)
                 temp.Mat[i][j]+=t.Mat[i][j]+this->Mat[i][j];
     }
    return temp; 
}


Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const Matrix &t)const//multiplay matrix on the right
{
    if (this->cols!=t.rows)
    {
      Matrix temp(this->cols,this->rows);
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=this->Mat[i][j];
      return temp;
    }
    else
    {
      Matrix temp(this->cols,t.rows);    
      for(int i=0;i<this->rows;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<t.cols;j++)
            for(int k =0;k<this->cols;k++)
                temp[i][j]+=this->Mat[i][k]*t.Mat[i][j];
      return temp;          
    }

}

Matrix  Matrix::operator *(const int &num)const //multiplay with number
{
    Matrix temp(this->rows,this->cols);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=this->Mat[i][j]*num;
    return temp; 
}

Matrix  Matrix::operator -(const Matrix &t)const //matrix subtraction 
{
    Matrix temp(this->rows,this->cols);  
    if (this->rows!=t.rows ||this->cols!=t.cols)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            temp.Mat[i][j]=this->Mat[i][j];
       return temp;
    }
    else
     {

         for(int i=0;i<this->rows;i++)
             for(int j=0;j<this->cols;j++)
                 temp.Mat[i][j]+=this->Mat[i][j]-t.Mat[i][j];
     }
    return temp;
}

Matrix::~Matrix ()//destrucor 
{
 for(int i =0;i<this->rows;i++)
   delete [] this->Mat[i]; 
 delete [] this->Mat;

}
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    Matrix m(2, 2);
    m[0][0] = 2;
    m[1][1] = 2;
    cout << m << endl;
    m = m;
    const Matrix s = -m;
    cout << m << endl << s << endl;
    m = s+2 * -m * m * 2 - s;
    cout << m << endl << s << endl;
    cout << s[1][1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You say it's working as expected, but you don't tell us what it's supposed to do. You've also been told not to use `using namespace std` in your code at [your previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147887/52915), yet you're still using it. Please elaborate both points.

Comment: On top of that, you're probably using multiple files. The formatting has made it one big code block. Try adding the file names in between for better context and splitting the code blocks as a side effect.

Comment: sorry I need to use operator overloading on matrix object. Things like * - + print using << and access specific cell with [] [] Regarding the issue with using namespace std I simply forgot :) I need to change it  –

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a number of things that could help you improve your code.

### Fix your formatting

There are abundant examples here of C++ code that is well formatted.  This code has peculiar and inconsistent indentation that makes it difficult to tell when a function begins and ends.  Fixing that would improve readability.

### Don't use std::endl unless you really need to flush the stream

The difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `std::endl` actually flushes the stream. This can be a costly operation in terms of processing time, so it's best to get in the habit of only using it when flushing the stream is actually required. It's not for this code.

### Don't overspecify member functions

The code currently includes these two lines in `Matrix.h`:

```
Matrix  operator -()const;
Matrix  Matrix::operator -(const Matrix &t)const;
```

The first one is fine, but the second one is overspecified.  Because it's already inside the `Matrix` class, it's not necessary to tell the compiler that it's inside the `Matrix` class.  It makes the code more cluttered and harder to read as well as being inconsistent, so that second line shoud instead be written like this:

```
Matrix operator-(const Matrix &t) const;
```

### Don't use `void main()`

The only function signatures allowed by the C++ standard both require an `int` return type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) for details.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It's particularly bad to use it when writing include headers.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The `Matrix.h` file refers to `std::ostream` uses `atoi` but doesn't `#include <iostream>`.  Also, carefully consider which `#include`s are part of the interface (and belong in the `.h` file, as with this one) and which are solely part of the implementation (and therefore should only be listed in the `.cpp` file.)

### Always put the class' own include first

If you get into the habit of always putting the `#include` file for the class first, you'll never have to worry about having insufficient include files in the header.  That is, for this case, if the first line of `Matrix.cpp` had been `#include "Matrix.h"`, your compiler would have been able to have pointed out the previous point to you.

### Fix your inserter

There is a `friend` in the code that looks like this:

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os , const Matrix & m )
{
    for(int i=0;i<m.rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m.cols;j++)
            cout <<m.Mat[i][j]<<"  " ;
        cout <<endl ;
    }
    return os ;
}
```

The error is that it is ignoring the pass `std::ostream` and using `cout` instead.  I'd write it like this:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix &m) {
    for (int i=0; i < m.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j < m.cols; ++j) {
            os << m.Mat[i][j] << "  " ;
        }
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Note that I've used the pre-increment rather than post-increment operators (not a big deal here, but a good habit to use) and introduced more whitespace to make it easier to read.  I've also added curly braces to make it very clear to the person reading the code what was actually intended.

### Use the C++ form of `#include` files

The code includes this line

```
#include <assert.h>
```

However that puts everything into the global namespace.  Better would be to explicitly use the C++ version which looks like this:

```
#include <cassert>
```

This puts things into the `std::` namespace and is a better way to do this for the standard C headers.

### Don't use `this->` in member functions

Using `this->rows` in a constructor is distracting and unhelpful.  Simply use `rows` instead.  If you're trying to avoid a name clash between passed parameters and internal variables, simply rename one of them.  One common idiom is to prefix every member data item with `m_`.

### Throw exceptions rather than asserts

It's good you're checking for problems in the code, but the C++ way of handling those kinds of things is by throwing an exception rather than termminating the program via an `assert`.

### Allow for range checking

Because `rows` and `cols` are private member functions, and because `operator[]` does no range checking, there is no way for the user to provide range checking because there is no way to recover the dimensions of the matrix.

### Make your base class destructor virtual

By default, a compiler-generated destructor is concrete rather than virtual, but this leads to problems with collections of objects. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873515/why-should-the-destructor-of-base-classes-be-virtual) for more details on why.

### Consider return a reference from `operator=`

The current `operator=` has this signature:

```
void operator=(const Matrix &otherM ) const;
```

This has two problems that I can see.  First, it shouldn't be `const` because it clearly alters the object (by definition!).  Second, declaring it as return `void` isn't necessarily wrong, but it would prevent doing assignment chaining and returning the value of an assignment.  Consider:

```
int a, b, c, d;
a = b = c = 5;
if (10 == (d = c+a)) {
    std::cout << "Addition works as expected\n";
}
```

That works just fine for `int`, but if we try that with your `Matrix` class it won't work for two reasons.  First, there's no default constructor, and second, `operator=` returns `void`.

### Prefer a single allocation

Instead of doing multiple allocations in the constructor, it would be simpler to do only a single allocation.  This is both faster and simpler.

### Be wary of returning pointers to internal data

There is a serious problem with the implementation of `operator[]` because it returns, in effect, a pointer to internal data.  Here are just two examples for why that's wrong:

```
int *kaboom;          // we use this later
const Matrix s = m;   // make a const copy
{ 
    const Matrix a = s;  // make a local copy
    a[1][1] = 5;         // this alters a const object! not good.
    kaboom = a[1];       // use operator[]
}  // a is now destroyed
kaboom[1] = 0;           // points to freed memory!  not good.
```

Comment: first of all thank you for the very detailed answer !
I change the format of matrix.cpp file is it better ? 
I removed the std::endl from my files in main file it's code I got from my teacher so I can't change it . 
You told me to "Throw exceptions rather than asserts"  what is the right way to do it ()?  
"Make your base class destructor virtual" I really don't understand what that means ? 
"Consider return a reference from operator=" I remvoed the const and I understand the concept but there is no need to return refernce in this assingmnet 
The new code in first comment

Comment: can you please check the things I changed  in the code ?

Comment: Changing the question after you've received answers invalidates the answers and isn't allowed.  The way to do it is to do everything you can to improve the code and then post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

- It is very beneficial to define `operator+()` in terms of `operator+=()`.
- `operator +(const int &num,const Matrix &t)` makes no mathematical sense. Besides, did you try to compile it?
- Adding (or subtracting) matrices of non-matching dimensions makes no sense, neither mathematical nor common. A condition

  ```
      if (this->rows!=t.rows ||this->cols!=t.cols)
  ```

  shall throw an exception, or signal an error in some appropriate way.
- `this->` is superfluous. An unqualified name refers to a member anyways.

Comment: It's telling that there's no test for that `operator+(int, Matrix)` given that it appears to be defined in terms of itself!  Perhaps it has been compiled, but I'm sure it hasn't been exercised.